# Silverlight deploy website with db on host not working

Tags: mysql, wcf, silverlight

i have built (locally) a silverlight website. It uses a mysql database (had to install mysql connector) and a wcf service to contact the db on the server.

Locally, everything works fine. However when i uploaded it on my host, the silverlight application loads OK, but t cannot get the data from the host database.

It's the first time i'm doing this, so there's probably something i do not know.
The steps i took in order to make this to work on my host are:

- I created a  database and uploaded all data from my local db.
- I uploaded all my site content (my ClientBin folder, my service.svc file, web.config and my App_Code folder)
- I changed the database name and access parameters on my web.config to point to my host's parameters
  What have i done wrong?
  Also, are all these files i have uploaded necessary or not?

  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the clientaccesspolicy.xml served up by the machine hosting the WCF service?  Silverlight requires this file to be present before consuming web services.  Normally you'd create a clientaccesspolicy.xml and place it in the root directory of the web server, but for WCF, you may have to generate the policy file from the WCF service itself:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/16839/57457.aspx